# AWS ELB and Nat Gateway not playing well together

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elb

I have a basic VPC with two Linux EC2 instances running Apache that live behind a classic ELB.

I want to use DynamoDB from the web app which requires that the EC2 instances have outbound internet access since the DynamoDB endpoint isn't available via backend.

I'm using the ELB to avoid having a public IP attached to the EC2 instances so i'd rather not attach them just so i can have access to DynamoDB.

At this point i get stuck.

I setup the new `NAT Gateway` feature to provide access to the DynamoDB public endpoint. This works well when configured meaning the web app can connect successfully to the DynamoDB endpoint BUT it breaks incoming traffic via the ELB.

With the Nat Gateway configured, the default gateway of the EC2 instances subnet is the Nat Gateway.

ELB requires that a Internet Gateway be present for routing to work... so its a catch 22 that i'm not sure how to work around.

To summarise, i want to provide external access to web servers via ELB and i want the web servers to have access to DynamoDB endpoint via a Nat Gateway. Without having to assign a public interface to the web server instances.

Does anyone know if this can work? Seems quite a standard setup. A reference architecture or tutorial would be great.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need (at least) two subnets for this setup:

One public subnet with `0.0.0.0/0` route to Internet Gateway (and of course Local route for VPC CIDR), and one private subnet with `0.0.0.0/0` route to Elastic interface of your NAT instance (and Local route for VPC CIDR).

Place your NAT instance and ELB in public subnet, and place your servers in 
private subnet.

Comment: ok thanks, will test again. I thought i had tried this setup and ELB health checks worked to ec2 instances but public traffic to ELB always failed to get reply. Perhaps i had ELB in wrong subnet.